# How to set variable in path - API Platform

Tags: symfony, swagger, api-platform.com

I am creating small API in Symfony and I am using Api Platform.

In `/src/BooksBundle/Resources/config/api_resources/resources.xml` I set path to:

```
<collectionOperations>
    <collectionOperation name="get">
        <attribute name="method">GET</attribute>
        <attribute name="path">/{shop}/books</attribute>
        <attribute name="normalization_context">
            <attribute name="groups">
                <attribute>books_list</attribute>
                <attribute>list</attribute>
            </attribute>
        </attribute>
    </collectionOperation>
</collectionOperations>
```

In `swagger.yml`, I have set path and parameter

```
paths:
/api/{shop}/books:
  get:
    tags:
      - Book
    operationId: getBookCollection
    produces:
      - application/json
      - application/ld+json
      - text/html
    summary: Retrieves the collection of Book resources.
    responses:
      '200':
        description: Book collection response
        schema:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Book-book_list'
      '401':
        description: Unauthorized
    parameters:
      - name: title
        in: query
        required: false
        type: string
      - name: shop
        in: path
        required: true
        type: string
```

My route is for example: `127.0.0.1/api/shopName/books?title=sometitle`
and in response I get this error: `Unable to generate an IRI for "BookBundle\Entity\Book".`

I investigated exception, and message is:
`Some mandatory parameters are missing ("shop") to generate a URL for route "api_books_get_collection".`

**So I need a way to send parameters through path in API Platform, cause for some reason, this doesn't work.**

---

Just for info why I think this is configuration issue. My parameter Shop in entity Book, have getter and setter and If I put fixed value in entity, remove parametar from both config and route, url `127.0.0.1/api/books?title=sometitle` works perfect and I get full Hydra Json response.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your route in a restful way in API Platform, like this:

```
GET /resource-name/id/resource-name/id
```

So you should probably do:

```
GET /shops/{shop-identifier}/books?title=sometitle
```

Let me know if that works, and always remember to follow the REST standard.